# Gradient is not working in IE-10

Tags: html, css

```css
.button button {
    background: linear-gradient(0 Bottom,  #00664F,  #64A70B);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(0 Bottom,  #00664F,  #64A70B);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 Bottom, Left Top, from(#00664F), to(#64A70B));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(73px Bottom,  #00664F,  #64A70B);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#00664F, endColorstr=#64A70B)
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#00664F, endColorstr=#64A70B)
     position:relative;
     border: medium none;
}
```

The Gradient is working fine is IE-8,9,Chrome,Mozzila but it is not working in IE-10. is any suggestion or solution for it

Comment: Try to reformat your CSS so we can see it without having to scroll that long. And the solutions that pop up on google when searching for "gradient ie10" are not even implemented, so..

Comment: I recommend using Colorzilla: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ that will sort your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS old browsers (7/8/9) recognize the filter directive:

```
.for-ms-only{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled='false',
        startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#55FFFF00)}
```

and for IE10 you got the other answer

Answer (score 1):

```
-ms-linear-gradient(top, #00664F, #64A70B); /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
linear-gradient(to Bottom,  #00664F,  #64A70B); /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use colorzilla to make your gradients with the tick for the IE9 support
http://www.colorzilla.com/**